# How to make a list of class types in cpp?

Tags: c++, class

Anyone know how to make a list of class types in cpp?
Like something like this:

```
std::map<ClassType, std::string> map;
map.insert(MyClass1, "MyClass1");
map.insert(MyClass2, "MyClass2");
```

Comment: How are you going to use the list after that?

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you do that with [std::type_index](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index).

```
std::map<std::type_index, std::string> map;
map[std::type_index(typeid(MyClass1))] = "MyClass1";

std::cout << map[std::type_index(typeid(MyClass1))] << '\n';
```

But if all you want is to map classes to names, you might just add a simple static method to all classes:

```
struct Foo {
  std::string_view name() { return "Foo"; }
};

// Foo::name(); works
// Also works with instances, foo.name();
```